# PHP json_encode failing

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to read this in Objective-C but I keep getting errors.

When I run the json through a validator it tells me it is ok. But `json_decode` gets a null value.

What am I missing?

```
$arrTest = array("key" => "This is a string");
echo json_encode($arrTest);

$ob =  json_decode($arrTest);

if ($ob === NULL) { 
    print "\nDang it";
}
```

Comment: `$arrTest` is an array, not a string.  You can't decode an array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) returns a new string, so you have to save that to a variable if you want to decode it later:

```
$arrTest = array("key" => "This is a string");
$jsonString = json_encode($arrTest);
echo $jsonString;

$ob =  json_decode($jsonString);

if ($ob === NULL) { 
    print "\nDang it";
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, it's been a long time since I've done any web front end work.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to decode the array, not the json string

Answer (score 1):

You are decoding the array not the encoded string.